# setIAM 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

```
resources:
- name: practice-service-account
  type: iam.v1.serviceAccount
  properties:
    displayName: practice-service-account
    projectId: {{ project }}
    accountId: practice-service-account
- name: get-iam-policy
  action: 'gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:cloudresourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy'
  properties:
    resource: resources-practice {# make this environment variable #}
- name: set-iam-policy
  action: 'gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:cloudresourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy'
  properties:
    resource: {{ project }}
    policy: $(ref.get-iam-policy)
    gcpIamPolicyPatch:
      add:
      - role: roles/viewer
        members:
        - user:email1@example.com
        - user:email2@example.com
        - user:email3@example.com
```

Why am I always experiencing the error below when trying to create these IAM resources?

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1544014242908-57c45d47a0760-6a2ec217-9ee53506]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/infrastructure/resources/set-iam-policy
  message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:cloudresourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"message":"The
    caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/resources-practice:setIamPolicy","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Comment: That reads to me that whoever is executing that deployment operation doesn't have the IAM permissions necessary to setIamPolicy. Might verify which account your using and what roles it has.

Comment: It seems the account you are using doesn't have "resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy" permission. Organization Administrator
 role (resourcemanager.organizationAdmin) has this permission which you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#using_predefined_roles). As [FridayPush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10240790/fridaypush) suggested, would you check which account your are using for the deployment operation and what role it has as well as permissions?

Comment: @FridayPush. My account is a project owner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deployment manager [acts using the `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` service account](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/access-control#access_control_for_deployment_manager). This error indicates that that service account doesn't have permission to change the IAM policy on that project. Try [granting](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) the service account the `iam.roleAdmin` role on the project (or `iam.organizationRoleAdmin` role on the organization).

Comment: I already made it Project Owner but I got this message instead. "There were concurrent policy changes. Please retry the whole read-modify-write with exponential backoff"

Comment: That means someone else tried to change the policy at the same time (maybe even deployment manager itself). Just keep trying until you are able to do the grant.

Comment: I am the only one doing something  in this project so I doubt there is "someone else". But yes I will keep on trying

Comment: As I poorly hinted, it's possible that deployment manager itself is the "somebody else". It may also be attempting to make IAM changes over and over again because they are being rejected. Maybe stopping deployment manager would allow your change to go through?

Comment: I found a workaround for that where I will first delete the serviceaccount resource in deployment manager then re-create it