# Google App Engine Resource Error on the Django Deployment Tutorial

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been looking for a great way to deploy my Django application and I found Google App Engine Flex a pretty good solution. I have not much experience in application deployment so I follow along with the [Official Google Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment#windows) about the deployment.

On the last step, the tutorial instructs me to deploy the application within the cmd prompt: `gcloud app deploy`.

I follow along. Everything seems fine until I get this message:

> Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...

After a while I get this message:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation <stuff..> error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-10-10T07:36:04.734Z7747.ue.0: Deployment Manager operation <stuff..> errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "<stuff...>"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"<stuff..>",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
]
```

Every time I rerun the command `gcloud app deploy` I get the exact same error. Any idea how to fix that? Google Search doesn't reveal anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try and give the following permissions to yourself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632902/setiam-403-forbidden) answer will help with some of the explanations.

[image]

Also, try and add the following in your `.yaml` file and see if it solves it

```
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 7
```

Comment: Wow, adding those lines* to the app.yaml actually fixed it.

Comment: Great. Seems like its due to scaling instances. one of those errors where it doesn't actually represent what the error is.